# Buffer not providing accurate geodesic buffers in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, buffer, geodesic

**This appears to only be a problem when using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.**

---

I created a shapefile following these criteria as recommended for Performing Geodesic Buffering:

The input feature class must be a point or multipoint dataset. (shapefile is a point)
The input feature class must have a geographic coordinate system. (GCS: Longitude/Latitude (WGS 84))
The buffer distance must be specified as a linear unit such as kilometers, miles, or feet. (Radius field (String) added with inputs 3 kilometers, 4.5 kilometers...)

I am not, however, getting accurate geodesic buffers. If I perform a buffer with the same shapefile and input a Linear Unit (3 Kilometers) instead of specifying by the field, I get accurate geodesic buffers.

This was the buffer used with a specified distance which gave me accurate geodesic buffers:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("test","C:/Temp/testBuffer.shp","3 Kilometers","FULL","ROUND","LIST","Site_Name")
```

This was the buffer used with a specified field and is NOT giving me accurate geodesic buffers:

```
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("test","C:/Temp/testBuffer2.shp","Radius","FULL","ROUND","‌​LIST","Site_Name")
```

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to indicate the exact usage you are submitting (presumably from two runs of the Buffer_analysis tool dialog), please?  If you repeat the buffers and use the **Geoprocessing | Results** window to right-click and **Copy As Python Snippet** then exactly what you did can be pasted into your Question ready to be formatted as Code.

Comment: This was the buffer usee with a specified distance which gave me accurate geodesic buffers: arcpy.Buffer_analysis("test","C:/Temp/testBuffer.shp","3 Kilometers","FULL","ROUND","LIST","Site_Name")

Comment: This was the buffer used with a specified field and is NOT giving me accurate geodesic buffers: arcpy.Buffer_analysis("test","C:/Temp/testBuffer2.shp","Radius","FULL","ROUND","LIST","Site_Name")

Comment: I just re-created your scenario and came up with the same puzzling answers - not sure what is going on here, but it appears that you cannot trust using the "Field" option - as far as using a WGS84 coordinates system goes anyways.

Comment: I am guessing despite what the help on the buffer tool says, it cannot read the units from a field and uses the default units of the projection system i guess.

Comment: "despite what the help on the buffer tool says, it cannot read the units from a field and uses the default units of the projection system." I was thinking the same thing, but have not found any documented bugs on this issue. I will keep looking but thank you for verifying the issue for me!

Comment: Does your layer have to be in a GCS?  Have you tried re-projecting it to a PCS and tested the buffer distance for both methods?

Comment: What is inaccurate about it? Is this problem only happening in ArcPy? I just tested this using the Buffer interface and I got the same result for both. Produced accurate results.

Comment: Could you provide the shapefile for use to try? From our testing it appears to be working correctly in recent releases. But maybe there is something about your data exposing a problem.
If ever you run into things not working as expected, please feel free to contact our customer support. We want to know in case there is something we can fix for everyone. 1 (888) 377-4575
Thanks.
Ken - ESRI

Comment: @Nicole Have you tried implementing the suggestions in my answer?  ArcGIS should not have any problem reading the units from your field.  In my testing, I have all my units in Title case.  I note that in your example above, you have yours in lower case.  Could you specify what you mean when you say the buffers are inaccurate?  I have tested the accuracy of my buffers by measuring the geodesic distance from the point to the buffer.  The key differences between my tests and your example are: using a geodatabase; using ArcGIS 10.3.

Comment: @dklassen - In WGS 84, if it was using the default units, it would be using decimal degrees, which would produce extremely large buffers.  Is this what is happening when you use the field to specify distance?

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this in ArcMap 10.3 and it has produced accurate buffers based on the field 'Dist' in my point feature class:  `arcpy.Buffer_analysis(in_features="//pmgfile01/Users/jb/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Point", out_feature_class="//pmgfile01/Users/jb/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb/Point_Buffer", buffer_distance_or_field="Dist", line_side="FULL", line_end_type="ROUND", dissolve_option="NONE", dissolve_field="", method="GEODESIC")`

---

Buffer Created with Dist field:
[image]

---

Buffer created setting distance to 1 Kilometer:[image]

---

I tested this in WGS 84.  Note that my distances in 'Dist' field look like this: "1 Kilometer".  Make sure the units are capitalized in the field.  Try loading your data into a geodatabase before running the buffers and see if that improves the result.  My point features were stored in a geodatabase and I output the buffers into the same geodatabase.  If none of that works, it is likely a bug with 10.0